# Application Default Credentials fails to create the Google App Engine service account credentials

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm working on an app that starts Google VM instances using a rest endpoint deployed on AppEngine.

when initializing Compute Engine API, I provide the application default credential (since I'm expecting that this will return the AppEngine service account credentials)

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
    List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
    // Set Google Compute Engine scope to Read-write.
    scopes.add(ComputeScopes.COMPUTE);
    credential = credential.createScoped(scopes);
}
return new Compute.Builder(httpTransport(), jsonFactory(), credential)
                  .setApplicationName(env.getProperty("spring.application.name"))
                  .build();
```

But I end up with the error :

```
java.io.IOException: Application Default Credentials failed to create the Google App Engine service account credentials
```

I 'm using libraries :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>${google-api-client.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-compute</artifactId>
    <version>${google-api-services-compute.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using **google-api-cient-appengine** instead of **google-api-client** :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
    <version>${google-api-client-appengine.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and initialized **GoogleCredential** using :

```
GoogleCredential credential = AppEngineCredentialWrapper.getApplicationDefault();
```

Comment: I need to ask a question that where are these default credentials stored?

Comment: If you deploy your app in GCP Appengine, getApplicationDefault will automatically fetch the credentials of the service account linked to appengine.
Otherwise, it will try to resolve variable Environment GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS which is the path to the json file containing service account credentials (if variable not resolved it ends with error)

Comment: I have a java application in my local and i want to authenticate to google cloud then what to do?

Comment: Are you using appengine devserver ?